# char () and int () are functions in c++?

Tags: c++

after 30 min of googling I decided to ask here my doubt 
It maybe invalid question if I am not understanding below line of code correctly

`result += char(int(text[i]+s-65)%26 +65);`

In above code char() is a function ? If yes so I am unable to find any information about it and if no so what is this ?
And same doubt for inner int() .

Above code is copied from a C++ program.

Comment: They are casts. I think you need to read a good C++  textbook.

Comment: Can you give a reference link @Neil Butterworth

Comment: In C++, this is known as a [functional cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast): "*The functional cast expression consists of a simple type specifier or a typedef specifier (in other words, a single-word type name: `unsigned int(expression)` or `int*(expression)` are not valid), followed by a single expression in parentheses. **This cast expression is exactly equivalent to the corresponding C-style cast expression**.*"

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast

Comment: Whoever wrote that line of code needs a different job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not functions. They're just alternate syntax for type-casting. `char(x)` is more-or-less equivalent to `static_cast<char>(x)`.

In general, in C++, one should prefer the C++-specific constructs for casting objects (`static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `const_cast`, and `reinterpret_cast`), as those help ensure you don't do anything dumb when casting objects. So in your code example, I'd recommend rewriting it as

```
result += static_cast<char>(static_cast<int>(text[i]+s-65)%26 +65);
```

But functionally, it's all identical.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau     `char(x)` is equivalent to `(char) x`?

Comment: @Aux Yes. I'm not sure what the order of operations is for stuff like `char(x) + 200` vs `(char)x + 200`, but `T(...)` and `(T)...` is equivalent for any type which doesn't have a constructor that takes `...` as arguments.

Comment: @Xirema See [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). `char(x)` and `(char)x` both have a higher precedence than `+`.

Comment: "But functionally, it's all identical" - Not quite. A C-style case (and a function-style cast) will start out trying to do a `static_cast` but if that fails it will attempt other casts, eventually degenerating into a `reinterpret_cast` followed by a `const_cast` (rarely what you want). The C++ casts don't have that problem (of trying multiple types of casts and just going with whatever succeeds first) - that's why C++ casts are safer and you should never write C-style (or function-style) casts in your code; it's really hard to work out what conversion they will *actually* end up doing.